# Enable TLS 1.0 using registry

Tags: windows-registry, ssl, tls

I am trying to enable TLS 1.0 in the client side computer .The client side computer is windows XP with IE 6 and server is windows server 2012 R2. In our server TLS 1.0 is enabled and SSL 3.0 and 2.0 is disabled . when I try to connect to server from windows XP by default the TLS 1.0 is disabled and SSL 3.0,2.0 is  enabled .

With this condition I cannot connect to server so I enabled TLS 1.0 in client XP computer through internet explorer advanced setting .Now the connection to the server is possible .

When I make registry setting using this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/dn786418.aspx) I cannot enable TLS 1.0 in the client side computer using registry.

How can I enable TLS 1.0 in client computer using registry? 
I require an automated solution like registry  so that I can do it in all PC's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way to enable `TLS 1.0` in the client computer using registry using the method shown below.

Go to the registry location `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings﻿`

Add new DWORD named SecureProtocols﻿ ﻿﻿﻿and assign a value of 170 (decimal).

Checking all protocols (`PCT1.0 + SSL2.0 + SSL3.0 + TLS1.0`﻿) present in the internet explorer will yield a new value of 170 .Value is based on the following calculation .

﻿Ex: `PCT1.0 + SSL2.0 + SSL3.0 + TLS1.0`

```
﻿2 + 8 + 32 + 128 = 170 Decimal or "aa" in Hex
```